# Case (In)Equality Operators '===' & !==' like Verilog in C

Tags: c

I have a simple C-Code that does integer comparison.

```
void evaluate_comparison (int addr, int expected, int got)
{
    if (got == expected) tunnel_pass (addr, got);
    else                 tunnel_fail (addr, expected, got);
}
```

The `expected` & `got` are actually 24-bit values corresponding to values written/read into a 24-bit DSP Core. (This C-Code gets compiled to Assembly & loaded into the DSP Core)

In Simulation, sometimes (esp. when some `addr` is not supported by the DSP), the DSP core reads `got = 24'hxxxxxx` (undefined 24-bit value). In this case, the above comparison passes, but I don't want it to.

I tried using `===` & `!==` Case Equality operators (similar to Verilog), but the Code won't compile. Is there any way of doing this in C ?

Comment: There is no === in C. For integers, == suffices, because integers can't be anything else than the value they're supposed to represent! Are you sure that the 24-bit values don't have any junk in the high 8 bits? You could do some extra range checking, just in case.

Comment: There can't be a `===` (case equality operator) for C, as the bits of an `int`s in C do not have a third state, unknown.

Comment: Hm, I just thought of a theoretical use case. What if you have an 1-complement system, then an int could be either +0 or -0. Then you'd need an === operator to distinguish between those. But I'm not sure how prevalent 1-complement systems are these days. But anyway, C doesn't have ===, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: @MRLister & @DanD : Thanks for the info.

But now, I am looking for alternate ways of making the comparison fail in case a `x` is encountered.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can write something like :

```
if (IsSupported(addr) && got == expected)
   tunnel_pass (addr, got);
else
   tunnel_fail (addr, expected, got);
```

However i don't know is it feasible to implement `IsSupported()` function in your case. 

At least maybe you can hard-code supported address ranges by hand.

Comment: You are right, I can do it that way for extra check. `IsSupported` can be implemented if I know the actual address-limit supported & hard-code it within the function.

However, I was actually writing a test to check the supported address limit of a RAM. Meaning, I wrote some unique data values to all possible (some higher number like 4K) RAM locations. Now I am reading back all RAM locations sequentially (`got`) & comparing them with the data written (`expected`).

I need to detect the addr-limit; till when the returned `got` data matches `expected` exactly; and after which the `got` is `x`.